# Dimmension of null spaces of a convergent sequence of operators

Tags: compact-operators

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. $A_\varepsilon, A$ are compact operators in $L(H,H)$ and $A_\varepsilon \to A$ in $L(H,H)$ as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$. We know that $\dim N(I-A_\varepsilon)$ and $\dim N(I-A)$ are finite, by Fredholm - Riesz theory. Prove that there exists a positive integer $n$ and a positive real number $\delta$ such that
$$\dim N(I-A_\varepsilon)\le n\quad \forall\ 0<\varepsilon<\delta.$$

I try to prove by a proof by contradiction, which leads to the existence of a sequence of compact operators $A_n$ such that $A_n\to A$, $\dim N(I-A_n)\to\infty$, but I can not get a contradiction, since I have no idea about the relation between $\dim N(I-A_n)$ and $\dim N(I-A)$.

Could anyone help me, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write $$ A = \underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^M \lambda_j \langle \varphi_j, \cdot \rangle \psi_j}_{:=B} + R $$ with $\Vert R \Vert <1/4$. Then for $\varepsilon$ small enough, we have $$ \Vert (I-A_\varepsilon) x \Vert = \Vert [(I-A)+(A-A_\varepsilon)]x \Vert \geq \Vert (I-B)x \Vert - (\Vert R \Vert + \Vert A-A_\varepsilon \Vert) \Vert x \Vert \geq \Vert (I-B) x \Vert - \frac{1}{4} \Vert x \Vert.  $$ Then I split $H=V\oplus V^\perp$ with $$ V=\text{span}(\varphi_j \ : \ j=1, \dots, M).$$ Then we should be able to use that $B\equiv 0$ on $V^\perp$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you very much. Your proof is very clear and helpful to me.

Comment: It is not really a proof. I have not checked whether the details work out, this is just my hunch as how to get started.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have checked it in details, and everything is ok.

Comment: Oh that's cool. Would you mind writing it up as an answer? I'd love to see how it is done in detail.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I add the proof below. Your idea is very clear, and I only add some details.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is compact, there exist orthonormal systems $\{\varphi_i\}, \{\psi_i\}$ in $H$ and a sequence $\lambda_i\to 0$ such that:
$$Ax=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i\langle x,\varphi_i\rangle \psi_i. $$
Let $N$ be a positive integer such that $|\lambda_i|<1/4$ for every $i> N$. Set
$$Bx=\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\langle x,\varphi_i\rangle \psi_i.$$
Then we have:
$$\|Ax-Bx\|^2=\sum_{i=N}^\infty \lambda_i^2\langle x,\varphi_i\rangle^2\le 1/16\|x\|^2$$
Set $Rx=Ax-Bx$, we have $\|B\|\le 1/4$. Since $A_\varepsilon \to A$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|A_\varepsilon -A\|\le 1/4$ for every $\varepsilon \in (0,\delta)$. We have
\begin{align*}
\|(I-A_\varepsilon)x\|&=\|(I-B)x + (A-A_\varepsilon)x-Rx\|\\
&\ge \|(I-B)x\|-\|Rx\|-\|(A-A_\varepsilon)x\|\\
&\ge\|(I-B)x\|-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|.
\end{align*}
Let $V={\rm span}(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_N)$. We have that $Bx=0$ for every $x\in V^\perp$, hence that $\ker(I-A_\varepsilon)\cap V^\perp=\{0\}$ and that $\dim N(I-A_\varepsilon)\le N$ (QED).

Comment: Nice answer. There is a minor typo, it should be $\mathrm{ker}(I-A_\varepsilon)\cap V^\perp = \{ 0 \}$ (not $=\emptyset$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you, I corrected the typo.